# How correct restore state on MVP

Tags: android, mvp

I use MVP and it's work fine.

1. User click button on the View
2. show progress
3. call peresenter.download file
4. after success download file call view.hideProgress

OK. It's work fine.

But has one problem.

When user click button the progressbar is show. But if I change screen orienation  then as result view is recreate and progress bar is hide. But operation was not finish yet. The operation is finish after 10 seconds.

So the question is:

How show progress bar (restore state) while file was not download success?

Comment: you can set a flag "isDownloading" which is set to "true" when you start downloading. and when screen rotates it never change class variable values so you can access that variable to show progress dialog agian on "configurationChanged()"

Answer (score 0):

You can use Moxy library. It helps to save and restore state on configuration changes because it adds ViewState layer.

https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy

If you prefer native ways you can use loaders or retain fragments